# Adjusting for timezones and DST

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

On my website, users can set preferences for their current timezone. I have a bunch of datetimes in my database, but I want to show each time appropriately, given A) what timezone they are in, and B) whether or not Daylight Savings is in effect.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a several-step process.

1. Allow the users to choose their timezone from the [Olson timezone database](http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm). It's probably already installed on your machine if you're on Linux or other Unices.
2. Store **all** dates and times as UTC. No exceptions.
3. When the user requests a page, load it up and whenever you need to format a time, use the user's timezone preferences and use timezone-aware formatting functions. Both PHP and Python have ways to store dates and times in a sensible manner.

   [Haluk has a good example of how to use PHP's DateTimeZone.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927703/mysql-adjusting-for-timezones-and-dst/1481498#1481498) However, if you're working with legacy code where you will only use one timezone in a request, you can use something like this; it's what I used when I customized PunBB to display timezones properly (I've since moved on from there...)

   ```
   /**
    * Sets up the timezone system. $timezone is the timezone. In PunBB, this is
    * called by setup_dates($pun_user['timezone']) in common.php.
    *
    * DON'T USE THIS unless you can't use PHP's DateTime module.
    */
   function setup_dates($timezone) {
       if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) {
           date_default_timezone_set($timezone) ;
       } else {
           putenv('TZ='.$timezone) ;
       }
   }
   ```

   In Python, use the [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) library, which should also already be installed on your server (again, assuming *nix). If it's not, ask your sysadmin to install it (distributions usually customize it to work off of the builtin timezone database), or alternately just install it using `easy_install`. pytz provides great [usage examples](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#example-usage). You'll want to use the `astimezone` method:

   ```
   >>> utc_dt = datetime(2002, 10, 27, 6, 0, 0, tzinfo=utc)
   >>> loc_dt = utc_dt.astimezone(eastern)
   >>> loc_dt.strftime(fmt)
   '2002-10-27 01:00:00 EST-0500'
   ```

   Do this each time you format a time for users to read.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. I've just changed my code to put in the time in the database with UTC_TIMESTAMP (mysql). How do I convert this time to the user's local time?

Comment: The steps I'm referring to are at the application level. Using these steps will allow you to keep track of the user's timezone and allow you to convert. If you're using PHP, using that function with the appropriate timezone will cause the time string-formatting functions to use the correct time zone, automatically compensating for DST.

Answer (score 1):

We use a date formatting method/function that adjusts for the user's timezone.  Date/times are stored in our local timezone (PST) and converted appropriately.

I've seen other systems that store everything in GMT using unix timestamps.  You will still need to convert it to the user's timezone.

Answer (score 1):

When I query my data I use the following PHP script

```
<?  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($registration)){ 
  
  $dt_obj = new DateTime($row['message_sent_timestamp']." UTC");
  $dt_obj->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Istanbul'));
  echo $formatted_date_long=date_format($dt_obj, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'); } ?>
```

You can replace the datetimezone value with one of the available [php timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) here:

Answer (score 0):

MySQL stores its native date/time types as UTC on the server and converts them to other timezones on a per-connection basis. If a connection does not specify a timezone it tries to use the servers time. You can read more about this [in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time-zone-support.html). But you should be able to do:

`SET time_zone = timezone;`

to the client timezone at the start of the query or if you do per request connections.